# How to remove a parent element, but keep its children elements in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am working on an AngularJS Project hosted on a SpringBoot App with Thymeleaf, and I that need AngularJS to grab JUST the section element from another webpage via views and routing.

However, I can't figure out how to make it so that ThymeLeaf only gives the section element instead of the whole HTML page, while still allowing me to view the webpage as a natural template when developing.

So in the server it is stored as

```
<html>
    <title>Don't keep this </title>
    <body>
        <section>
            Keep this
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when AngularJS reads the page, Thymeleaf makes it read this:

```
<section>
    Keep this
</section>
```

Comment: can you add your Thmeleaf template and your JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is pretty simple with fragments.  If your html file looks like this:

```
<!-- whatever.html -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Don't keep this </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section th:fragment="section">
            Keep this
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And your controller, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "whatever.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get() {
    return "whatever :: section";
    // Where the string 'whatever' resolves to the template, and section
    // resolves to the text in th:fragment.
}
```

It will return the html

```
<section>
    Keep this
</section>
```